# Counter contain 10 digits

Tags: java, count

I am working on a basic Java app. I want to assign an ID to each person. The ID should contain 10 digits. 
for example:
0000000001
0000000002

how should I set my count

```
  private static int count= 0;
  private int id;
  private String Name;
```

Comment: suppose you can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227787/java-unique-10-digit-id)

Comment: Set the count at `1000000000`

Answer (score 1):

Just change your id to String and then calculate it in constructor using *String.format()*

```
String id = String.format("%010d", count);
```

where first "0" in "%010d" tells method to pad given in argument number with zeros, and "10" is a length of the result.